# How to merge arrays in two objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got something like:

```
var object1 = { 'tab1' : [{ test : 10 }, { test : 15 }], 'tab2' : [{ test : 15 }] };

var object2 = { 'tab2' : [{ test : 35 }, { test : 25 }], 'tab3' : [{ test : 40 }] };
```

And I need the result:

```
var object3 = { 
    'tab1' : [{ test : 10 }, { test : 15 }],
    'tab2' : [{ test : 35 }, { test : 25 }, { test : 15 }],
    'tab3' : [[{ test : 40 }]
};
```

How can I do that?

`$.extend(true, object1, object2)` returns object without `{ test : 15 }` in `tab2`

Comment: the order in tab2 is not random, first should be objects from tab2 object2 and than rest

Comment: @howderek he said what he tried: he tried a `$.extend` call which didn't give him `test : 15` in teh results.

Comment: You're looking for a _deep_ merge, which jQuery doesn't support. You'll have to do some sort of recursive merge.

Comment: @EliGassert thank you, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use javascript here, something like

```
var merged = [];
for (var key in object1) {
    if (object1.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       var obj1Arr, obj2Arr;
       obj1Arr = object1[key];
       obj2Arr = object2[key];

       if (obj1Arr) merged = merged.concat(obj1Arr);
       if (obj2Arr) merged = merged.concat(obj2Arr);
       object3[key] = merged;
        merged = [];
    }
}

for (var key in object2) {
    if (object2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !object3[key]){ // ignore the keys we already found
       var obj1Arr, obj2Arr;
       obj1Arr = object1[key];
       obj2Arr = object2[key];

       if (obj1Arr) merged = merged.concat(obj1Arr);
       if (obj2Arr) merged = merged.concat(obj2Arr);
       object3[key] = merged;
       merged = []; 
    }
}
```

console.log(object3)
and a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/H4UGb/1/

you could clean this up a bit by putting the common code in the if statements into a function...

Comment: almost great, but remember about that
_the order in tab2 is not random, first should be objects from tab2 object2 and than rest_

Comment: then switch which array gets merged first